# Почему CommandParameter == null?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть кнопочка, к которой привязана команда

```
<Button Command="local:ItemViewModel.Increment" CommandParameter="{Binding CurrentItem}"/>
```

`CurrentItem` здесь отражает `SelectedItem` некоего листбокса. В момент, когда проверяется возможность выполнения команды, `CurrentItem` имеет значение (проверил в отладке), но в `CanExecute` команды все равно передается `null`.

Если я делаю так

```
<Button Command="local:ItemViewModel.Increment" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=lstItems}"/>
```

то все работает. Но такой вариант меня не устраивает. Почему в первом случае параметр равен `null`?

Answer (score 1):

Опять сам спросил, сам ответил. Походу, `CommandParameter` кэшируется и подписывается на `PropertyChanged`. В итоге помогло срабатывание этого события при изменении свойства `CurrentItem`. Майкрософт не перестает удивлять. :/

Comment: С другой стороны, я бы просто рекомендовал избегать использования  `CommandParameter`, кроме простых случаев.

Comment: Вынесите CurrentItem в вашу VM, команду привяжите к VM, пользуйтесь.

Comment: @Monk, CurrentItem и так в ВМ расположен.

Comment: Так и обращайтесь к свойству в ВМ, а не передавайте снаружи.

Comment: @Monk, спасибо за совет. Возможно, я именно так и сделаю в конечном итоге. В данный момент я делаю экзамплы по командам.

Comment: @VladD, параметры добавляют универсальность. Так что для простых случаев как раз и нет смысла использовать параметры. ИМХО )

Comment: @iRumba: Мой опыт говорит об обратном. Лучше иметь много команд, чем одну команду пытаться переиспользовать, надеясь на параметр. Думайте о команде как о сущности, а не о куске кода. Тогда станет понятно, почему лучше каждому Item'у раздать по команде.

Comment: @VladD, у меня в этом опыта нет вообще, но на ум приходят команды, типа Copy, Paste, Print, Save, которые очень не хочется дублировать.

Comment: Такие команды реализуются через RoutedCommand, если ничего не путаю. Параметры там тоже не нужны.

Comment: @Monk, допустим, нужно напечатать содержимое элемента управления, который расположен на одном из табов. Есть команда Print. С параметром я просто передам нужный элемент управления в команду на форме, а без параметра мне придется на каждый элемент подключать команду печати, к тому же я эту команду не смогу вынести в главное меню формы.